# Finding the probability and expected value

Tags: statistics, poisson-distribution

**The scientist Harry wants to study the lion population in two different areas, Area 1 and Area 2. He assumes that the number of lions, X and Y, in Areas 1 and 2 is Poisson distributed.The ecologist reckons that the expected number of lions is respectively $λ_1 = 3$ in area 1 and $λ_2 = 5$ in area 2**

**(a) If a lion is in such an area, Harry assumes a probability of 0.4 that
it is observed. If in reality there are 5 lions in the area, what is the probability that
three of them are observed? What is the expected number of lions observed?**

So I have been told that this is binomial distribution problem, is this true? And how is this a binomial problem, and why does the problem talk about Poisson distribution then?

Comment: the poisson models the number of lions in the area, while the binomial the number of lions observed  when you already know how many of them are inside the area

Comment: Ok, I see. Thank you so much for your answer :)

Comment: glad to have helped :)